# Data is not retrieving from android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve  data from sq lite  database in array list in toast message, but showing

**[ util.AllProfileElement @4b0ae658,util.AllProfileElement @4b0a258c,...........]**

like something my data is save  in database which  i confirm through  toast message please help me get out of this
`enter code here`

**Database Helper Class:**

```
package database;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

   public class DatabaseHeleper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "profile.db";
// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
//table name
public static final String PROFILE_TABLE_NAME = "profile_table";

// Table Columns names
public static final String COL_PROFILE_ID = "id";
public static final String COL_PROFILE_NAME = "name";
public static final String COL_PROFILEE_GENDER = "gender";
public static final String COL_PROFILE_BLOOD = "blood";
public static final String COL_PROFILE_AGE= "age";
public static final String COL_PROFILE_HEIGHT= "height";
public static final String COL_PROFILE_WEIGHT = "weight";

// table information
private static final String DATABASE_PROFILE_TABLE = "create table "+ PROFILE_TABLE_NAME  + 
        "( " + COL_PROFILE_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + " "            
        +  COL_PROFILE_NAME  + " text not null," + " "
        + COL_PROFILEE_GENDER + " text not null," + " "
        + COL_PROFILE_BLOOD + " text not null," + " "
        + COL_PROFILE_AGE + " text not null," + " "
        + COL_PROFILE_HEIGHT + " text not null," + " "          
        + COL_PROFILE_WEIGHT + " text not null);";



public DatabaseHeleper(Context thiscontext) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(thiscontext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_PROFILE_TABLE);     
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(DatabaseHeleper.class.getName(),  "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");       
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_PROFILE_TABLE);       
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

a**nd ******Database Source code is**:******

```
enter code here



 package database;

   import java.util.ArrayList;

   import util.AllNameList;
   import util.AllProfileElement;


   import android.content.ContentValues;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.SQLException;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

    public class DatabaseSource {

    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    private DatabaseHeleper mHelper;




    public DatabaseSource(Context thiscontext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mHelper = new DatabaseHeleper(thiscontext);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        mDB = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        mHelper.close();
    }


    public long insertData(AllProfileElement object) {

        try {
            open();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();     

        values.put(DatabaseHeleper.COL_PROFILE_NAME, object.getName());
        values.put( DatabaseHeleper.COL_PROFILE_AGE, object.getAge());
        values.put( DatabaseHeleper .COL_PROFILEE_GENDER, object.getGender());
        values.put( DatabaseHeleper .COL_PROFILE_BLOOD, object.getBlood());     
        values.put( DatabaseHeleper .COL_PROFILE_HEIGHT,object.getHeight());
        values.put( DatabaseHeleper .COL_PROFILE_WEIGHT, object.getWeight());

        long inserted = mDB.insert( DatabaseHeleper. PROFILE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        close();

        this.close();

        return inserted;
    }
    //public ArrayList<AllProfileElement> getAllProfile() {
    public ArrayList<AllProfileElement> getAllProfile() 
    {
        //ArrayList<AllProfileElement> allprofile = new ArrayList<AllProfileElement>();
        ArrayList<AllProfileElement> allprofile = new ArrayList<AllProfileElement>();
    /*  try {
            open();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Cursor mCursor = mDB.query(DatabaseHeleper.PROFILE_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null,
                null, null);*/

        try {
            open();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Cursor mCursor = mDB.query(DatabaseHeleper.PROFILE_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null,
                null, null);



        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (mCursor != null && mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();

            for (int i = 0; i < mCursor.getCount(); i++) {

                int mID = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHeleper.COL_PROFILE_ID));
                String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHeleper.COL_PROFILE_NAME));
                String age = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHeleper.COL_PROFILE_AGE));                        
                String gender = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHeleper.COL_PROFILEE_GENDER));
                String blood = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHeleper.COL_PROFILE_BLOOD));
                String height = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHeleper.COL_PROFILE_HEIGHT));
                String weight = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHeleper.COL_PROFILE_WEIGHT));
                AllProfileElement mProfile = new AllProfileElement(mID, name,age,gender,blood,height,weight);

                allprofile.add(mProfile);
                mCursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        mCursor.close();
        mDB.close();

        // return place list
        return allprofile;
    }

    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're implicitly calling `toString()` on an ArrayList of AllProfileElement objects somewhere. Please post the code for the Toast.

Comment: I have a big code in activity with other element, here i am only providing toast message where i am calling array list    ArrayList<AllProfileElement>profile =obj.getAllProfile();
  for(int i=0;i<profile.size();i++)
  {
    
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),profile+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
 }

Comment: Well that's exactly what @Mike M said. You are setting the message of your toast to profile+"" but profile is an ArrayList so it is returning the toString() return value of the ArrayList. Instead you want to set the message to profile.get(i).getName(). getName() being (I assume) an accessor in your Profile object for the name variable.